# how to scale a socket.io application on multiple servers?

Tags: node.js, redis, socket.io

I have read a lot of stuff about custering, redis but I could not find any real sample.

I have a simple socket.io application and I need to scale this application to many servers.

Looks like socket.io and RedisStore is the solution.

Does anyone has a real world nippet on how he uses socket.io on many servers ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to `npm install` the package `socket.io-redis`. Then start the server by command `redis-server`. 
Add the following lines to your code.

```
var io = require('socket.io')(3000);
var redis = require('socket.io-redis');
io.adapter(redis({ host: 'localhost', port: 6379 }));
```

Then you need to modify your nginx configurations file to enable load balancing as in, http://socket.io/docs/using-multiple-nodes/#nginx-configuration

```
upstream io_nodes {
   ip_hash;
   server 127.0.0.1:6001;
   server 127.0.0.1:6002;
   server 127.0.0.1:6003;
   server 127.0.0.1:6004;
}
```

Restart your nginx server and then run node server. This should scale your server too.

Comment: Sorry But I don't understand it well: it looks like you load balance on SAME server (127.0.0.1) whereas the goal is to scale the socket.io on MULTIPLE servers

Comment: Refer this link. It should help. http://www.ranu.com.ar/2011/11/redisstore-and-rooms-with-socketio.html

Comment: this is just 1 server sample